# Hide Android KitKat 4.4 printing dialog

Tags: android, printing, android-4.4-kitkat, android-print-framework

I am working on a kiosk app which needs to print. I have the printing functionality working but the problem is it shows a dialog and as a kiosk app we need to keep things simple and limit what users can do.

Is there a way to print without showing the dialog?

I don't care if it prints to the "default" printer or if it's something I'll need to pass parameters into.

I used this for reference: http://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html

Comment: The only print functionality I can find is the `print()` method, which will show the dialog every time. You might check the `PrintManager.java` source as well as the dialog's source to see what they're doing under the hood, but it doesn't look like you can do it with the *documented* API methods.

Comment: I assumed that would be the case but I will take a look at the source and see if I can find something.

Comment: _"Is there a way to print without showing the dialog?"_ No, there isn't. You can't do it without customizing the sources. Look at [Issue with Print dialog for Printing](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160908).